# MySQL GTID Replication Confusion

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain how MySQL GTID replication is different/better than regular binary log replication? I've read through the docs but can't get a concise answer to the following:

- How does GTID preserve the right order of transactions? Is there any sort of sequencing logic?
- Can it be set-up on a MySQL 5.7 source to a MySQL8.0 replica?
- Can an existing binlog replication be "switched" over without much downtime to GTID replication? Or must a new mysqldump be first made? What is the process of switching over?
- What main benefits does it provide over regular binary log replication? I've read it is "autopositioning" but how does that work and affect the sequencing logic of transactions?
- Technically, what are the main differences (and what benefits do those differences bring), a summary would be great! I realize a lot of the above questions are asking this already.

I really appreciate the assistance and apologize if my question is a bit too high level.